# Extracting timestamp into variable in jmeter using regex

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm trying to extract a timestamp like hh:mm:ss into a jmeter variable using this regex:

```
(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)
```

But this is only getting me the first hh part.

Comment: I guess you are using `$1$`, so try `(\d+:\d+:\d+)`. Or, use `$0$` variable with a mere `\d+:\d+:\d+`.

Comment: Tried the first one and it has worked, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined 3 capturing groups with 3 paired unescaped parentheses.

I guess you are using a default `$1$`, so, use just

```
(\d+:\d+:\d+)
```

Or, use `$0$` variable with a mere `\d+:\d+:\d+`.